# Why is the protein ubiquitin so ubiquitous?

Tags: biochemistry, physiology, proteins

[Ubiquitin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquitin) is a protein tag that is attached to proteins in order to mark them for destruction/proteolysis by the cell. This system is sometimes used for clearing out harmful viral proteins that infect the cell, but is used in concert with the [26S proteasome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteasome) to degrade proteins in many cells throughout the body. I just want to know why is ubiquitin so ubiquitous?

Comment: First, plus points for the pun.
Second, I suppose natural selection is at play. Those cells which don't have proteases like ubiquitin would die, and the ones with the enzyme would survive. 

(Just my opinion. I don't have any source, I'm sorry)

Comment: when I was in graduate school I worked with a faculty member - https://profiles.psu.edu/profiles/display/112215 - who had done a lot of work in the basic biochemistry of the ubiquitin-proteasome pathway. He had been in the field when it was still very young/early and knew many of the early players in that field of research. He always said that the protein was named "ubiquitin" because in nearly every tissue or cell they looked they found it being expressed - they figured it must be important if it was expressed in nearly every tissue they looked in... turns out they were correct

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? It is used by all cells and that's why it is ubiquitous. Just like why actin is ubiquitous.

Comment: @MalharKhushu ubiquitin is not a protease, or any other kind of enzyme. It is a small marker protein that is covalently attached to other proteins (and itself) by ubiquitin ligases to perform a number of signaling functions, *including* targeting their substrates to the proteasome for degradation.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for the heads up, I'll edit my comment

Comment: @MalharKhushu Of course natural selection is at play. Isn't it everywhere? ;-)